# Should the “gas-limit” tag be changed?

Tags: discussion

The "gas-limit" tag refers to transaction gas limit, right? But "gasLimit" in the chain spec file and genesis file refer to BLOCK gas limit, right?

I can't get a straight answer on that but if that is correct, then it is not great to have "gas-limit" *tag* mean something different from "gasLimit" *parameter*, because intuitively, a person would assume these are the same.

Answer (score 1):

The information on a tag can be edited (with enough reputation).  I edited it to include the block gas limit.  Separating out into 2 tags is unlikely to be worth the effort: for example, fixing/remove the smart-tokens tag would seem to be higher priority.

I also think the single tag for gas-limit is reasonably helpful, a little similar to the gas tag but more specific: for example, someone following the gas-limit tag to answer questions about it, probably will not be bothered that there are 2 types of gas limit that they have to work with.

Comment: Those working on dApps probably only care about transactional `gasLimit`.  block `gas-limit` is hopefully a rarer occurrence, other than you need to know that `gasLimit` should be less than `gas-limit`.   The downside is IF there are a lot of `gas-limit` style questions then it will be more difficult to find the correct question, leading to more duplicates.  Only way to find out is to try it...

Comment: @Paul S What about all the people *not* working on dApps?  I don't even know what a dApp is and I've been dealing with (block) gas limit problems for weeks.  And half the time someone responds, it's about xaction gas limit instead.  since there are two concepts, there should be two tags: block-gas-limit and transaction-gas-limit.

Comment: @stone212 2 tags is ideal if set up and maintained but my observation in this community is most askers and answerers are not vigilant.  Most askers are not going to carefully use the right tag.  Also, most answerers do not bother correcting tags if needed, let alone titles which are even more important for question clarity.  Unfortunately, you will probably end up with little gain for the effort of retagging questions and then correcting when they are misused.

Comment: @eth I think this is backwards.  If there are two tags, it becomes necessary for users to choose the right one exactly *because* you can't simply type "gas-limit" and go away.  You have to choose, which means you will see that there are two meanings of the word.  If I had seen that, it would have saved me 15 hours.

Comment: @eth "for example, someone following the gas-limit tag to answer questions about it, probably will not be bothered that there are 2 types of gas limit that they have to work with" <-- maybe true.  But I do not think about the people answering, but the people searching for answers.  Anyway, this is an improvement definitely.

Comment: please provide references to the block gas-limit questions, now, I'm very curious (and by not being able to find them, a point is proven :-)

Comment: @stone212 I agreed with you on the ideal. But in observed practice, people either don't care much or are not as observant as you may think: I just cleaned up three questions with the tag "deploy", when there's already 350+ questions with "contract-deployment"...

Comment: @Paul S  I tried to link to some but they won't fit in comments.  Can you search for my recent questions (1-3 weeks ago?)

Comment: @eth I see your point.  Okay so there is one solution that I think meets this ideal without creating lots of "gas-limit" tags that should be better defined: restrict "gas-limit" and "gasLimit" from being used as tags.  The result will be that typing either of those will give you the multiple choice of gas limit-associated tags, and the user will have to choose one - very possibly learning that there are two or more definitions in the process.  If I had seen that, it would have saved me HOURS.

Comment: `gasLimit-transactions` and `gas-limit-blocks`?

Comment: @stone212 It's actually hard to restrict or blacklist a tag... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239189/how-should-we-make-tag-blacklist-requests  (The only one that I can remember is the smart-contracts tag.)  The gas-limit tag now has an improved description which may have helped save you time and to help someone in the future save time, which seems to be one of your goals, maybe the effort could be put to edit it further with more details (rather than trying to restrict tags etc).

Comment: @eth That is an improvement.  I don't think I am able to edit tags.  I would only suggest changing "a transaction or block gas limit" to "either the transaction limit or block gas limit" to be explicit.  And if restricting the tag is difficult, then this is fine.  But for the record, I was not suggesting censorship, just the removal of ambiguous terms.  Anyway this is a real improvement.

Comment: @stone212 Done, thanks for your suggestion.